# Moving to Eclipse RCP from Eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I am working with Eclipse Plugin development since 3 year but now i want to move to Eclipse RCP and RAP. I had tried and found it is bit similar and common things to work.

Now I want a better way to start with RCP and RAP. please share me what are the points that i have to take care and please share me some good tutorial link.

I had tried to search over google but getting a quit sure shot link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no real differences between RCP and Eclipse IDE applications, except maybe a reduced set of plug-ins to rely on (but they can be brought back). What you might have to take extra care is branding (and theming), and packaging (possible via products). Some RCP tutorials to start with:

- [Eclipse 4 RCP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html)
- [Old, 3.x RCP API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse3RCP/article.html)
- [Products and deployment](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html)

In case of RAP, the difference is bigger, as you have to manage the different sessions of different users, and theming is more important. A tutorial for the RAP-based issues (including tips for single sourcing RCP and RAP applications) are available from [eclipsesource.com](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tutorials/#rap).

A final note: if you are starting a brand new project, I'd rather experiment a bit with the 4.x API, as it is simpler to manage between RCP and RAP.

Answer (score 2):

Another source of information about Eclipse RAP in particular is the official RAP Developers Guide which can be found on the Eclipse Foundation website:

- http://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/